# How to fetch data from Zoho Inventory into Zoho Creator

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

```
response = zoho.inventory.getRecords("Item","i inserted ID in here");
var = response.get("Product Name");
for each  hey in var
{
    insert into SKU #SKU is a form in Zoho Creator
    [
        Added_User=zoho.loginuser
        Item_Name=hey #Item_Name is my field in SKU
    ]
}
```

Above code not fetching the Product Name Data from Inventory into Zoho Creator

Answer (score 1):

To serarch in Inventory you must use:

```
<response> = zoho.inventory.getRecords(<module>, <org_id>, [<criteria_map>], [<connection>]);
```

The module is **Items**. In "Settigs" -> "Profile organization" you can obtain your org_id. It returns a map and you have to iterate over response.get("Items")

I you want to get a single item and you have the ID you can use the next function

```
<response> = zoho.inventory.getRecordsByID(<module>, <org_id>, <record_id>, [<connection>]);
```

If you want to view the reponse, you can use "info response;" or "alert response;" depend where you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you are using the correct link name of 'Product Name' field, try 'Product_Name' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please Used the Correct API Name for fetch out in Map.

getRecords()- used to get all records (200) at time & for  Individual records try this:getRecordsByID()

Answer (score 0):

```
response = zoho.inventory.getRecords("Item","i inserted ID in here");
```

Org id is missing in this get record code.

```
var = response.get("Product Name");
```

make sure you are using a correct api name of the product name